# Node.js/MongoDB limit returns more records

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have searched but I cannot find any answer. Whilst the irregularity is not a problem, I'm more curious to why it is happening.

When I make a fairly simple find against a collection with 100k records with a limit of any number above 100 or 200 the console.log in the code snippet below always reports more records returned.

```
    var collection = db.collection('mycoll');

    collection.find({}).sort({created_date: -1}).limit(500).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        db.close();

        console.log(docs.length);
    });
```

With a limit of 500 it returns 590 or 591, any ideas?

EDIT: The issue seems to be related to this piece of code - https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.0/lib/cursor.js#L596

Comment: What MongoDB client are you using?

Comment: I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb to make the connection & collection. I've never come across this issue before, so I'm a little puzzled.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but have you tried flipping the order between `sort` and `limit`?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not make any difference. I ran the script three times: 588, 572 & 579.

Comment: Also shouldn't matter, but try if any different using `find({$limit: 500})`.

Comment: I found why it is happening, this block here - https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.0/lib/cursor.js#L596

If I comment that block out I get the correct length back. Also if I approach using cursor.each it works fine too. I've gone with the latter.

Answer (score 2):

skip and limit options are included as a second argument in the `find()` method. **(not tested)**

You can try out following:

```
collection.find({}, {sort: {created_date: -1}, limit: 500});
```

**EDIT**

Can you try out only this (limit) with created_date in asc order first?  This work for mongo node driver 1.4

```
var options = {
  "limit": 20,
  "sort":"created_date"
};

collection.find({},options).toArray();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't resolve the issue, this irregularity seems to be related to https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.0/lib/cursor.js#L596

Comment: fetch() is undefined on the cursor returned from node-mongodb-native.

Comment: the code needed a callback for toArray() but yes 20 works fine, 200 works fine. However higher numbers such as 300, 400 & 450 all returned 453 results. It all seems related to that "if I have a buffered count". I've worked around this by using cursor.forEach (or .each in the library I am using). I just found it to be strange behaviour but thanks for the help trying to resolve it, I appriciate it.